# play a sound from an arbitrary position

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, audio

I'm looking for a way to play an audio file from just any point in the file.
Currently, whenever I play the file, it just starts from the beginning.
Since it is a loop, I could choose to let it loop, and open/close the volume at will, but I think it is kind of a lame solution, not in the least because of battery concerns.
I really did some research on this, but it is either a freak requirement, or I don't know how to phrase my queries.
Thanks in advance for any tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be a nice easy problem to solve.  You don't post any code, so we can't see what you're trying at the moment.  What I'd do is this:

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SoundFile" ofType:@"wav"];
AVAudioPlayer * soundData =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath] error:NULL];

[soundData stop];
soundData.currentTime = 22; //This will start playback 22 seconds into the file
[soundData play];
```

It goes without saying that you need to check the duration of your sound file so that you don't select a time beyond its end!

currentTime is a float (so you can specify millisecond values).  You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/currentTime

Comment: wow. that simple. I really went through the documentation, but somehow missed that property....

Comment: Yeah - I find I often end up banging my head on something that ends up being a simple fix (hence the name headbanger!)